# can .find() method retrieve <a> tag values?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

i am trying to retrieve values from a button using jquery. the thing is i dont want to have a button in my html, i want an anchor tag. is there a way to retrieve the value from the anchor tag using jquery?
i want it to be and anchor tag so that i can easily style it with images, a button looks a bit out of place on my website

this is what i am doing right now:

```
   var mssg_id = $(this).find('button[name="fav"]').val();

   <button type="submit" name="fav"  value="<?php echo $row['msgid']; ?>"  >
   <i class="fa fa-heart" ></i>
   </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use data attributes like `data-value` instead.

Here is the working example which you can modify to better suit your needs:

== HTML ==

```
<a name="fav" data-value="<?php echo $row['msgid']; ?>">
   <i class="fa fa-heart">Some Dummy Text</i>
</a>
```

== jQuery ==

```
$('a[name="fav"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var mssg_id = $(this).attr('data-value');
    console.log(mssg_id);
});
```